It looks like this app isn't available facebook login
I am tring to facebook login with business. but not able to login with other user. Other then the admin of the app.
I have tried all the settings and Url set. but stil not able to find the solution.
So please provide any working solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
